# couchdb read authentication

Tags: authentication, couchdb

how can i handle read authentication in couchdb? i know roles can be defined in seperate databases but i want to implement read authentication on document level. i am thinking about using node.js but it does not seem an elegant solution because couchdb also has a http server and i dont want to add one more (or another application server like ruby or python). is there anyone working on this?

Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2765165/couchdb-read-authentication

Answer (score 5):

In the recent O'Reilly web cast on [CouchDB](http://www.oreillynet.com/pub/e/1588), J. Chris Anderson mentioned that read authentication was best handled by a combination of partial replication and multiple databases per reader group. Each database would contain only the documents pertaining to that specific group.

It makes the most sense when you think of each readers CouchDB as a filtered instance of an authority database.

Comment: Hey, BigBlueHat! Welcome to Stack Overflow! +1

Answer (score 4):

That's basically the correct answer. What I'd add is that document-level read control is *hard* to get right, especially in the presence of views. Filtering map rows at read-time is doable, but not very IO efficient. Generate reduction values based on filtered map rows, however, is prohibitively expensive.

For those reasons we encourage you to operate something like a database per access group, and make the entire database readable by all users.