# CouchDB read authorization

Tags: authentication, couchdb

In couchdb website -> technical overview -> security and validation - 
http://couchdb.apache.org/docs/overview.html - it writes that (on reader access 
part) "To protect document contents, CouchDB documents can have a reader list. 
This is an optional list of reader-names allowed to read the document. When a 
reader list is used, protected documents are only viewable by listed users." I 
searched about how to use it but i found nothing. So is it actually used and if 
it is how?

Thanks.

-- Mustafa

Answer (score 13):

You are right, it is confusing. Please see the [0.11 "breaking" changes](http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/Breaking_changes#Changes_Between_0.10.x_and_0.11.0) for more information.

**Per-document read control is not possible**; the `readers` field is for *access to the entire DB*. For more information, load your database in Futon and click the `Security...` link at the top.

The reason read control is not possible is because views (map and reduce) can draw information from all documents in the database, so it is generally impossible to prevent users from seeing private data in some form.

For detailed access control, you have two major choices:

1. Have an application between your users and the DB. 99% of web applications using MySQL do this already (e.g. Ruby on Rails). Keep ACL information in the DB and your application grants/rejects access based on the ACL.
2. Keep a dedicated database per user. You may have to modify your architecture but maybe not. You can use replication with a filter to copy only a user's data into his database. Then he reads from his database and writes to the central database.

Comment: Any plans to change this in the near future?

Comment: I do not expect a change to the architecture in the foreseeable future; however I definitely expect tooling to help smooth out development. For example, an automated way to have per-user database with only a subset of the data would be very welcome by the community!

Comment: Hi, Tyler. One year later and this is being proposed among the developers. Chris has an idea for full-featured access control lists. Also, I am sketching an idea for users who *may not* query documents, but who *may* query `_show` functions. Hopefully there will be more options soon.

Comment: I'm facing similar challenges, and would love to see some of those options/tools. Has anything come through in version 1.2?

Answer (score 0):

1. Login to the CouchDB as admin.
2. Open a particular database you want to secure
3. Click on **Security** button of that particular database.
4. Add users to **Members** names who can read. (At least add admins username) as string element of an array.
   **Ex.**
   Names: ["username1", "username2"]
5. Click on update button

[Click here to see the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qcy7T.png)

Comment: he was asking about document access, not database access.